# Translation keywords in second level not work

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.3

I am using the translator component of symfony, always i have used this component and its work correctly, but, in a new project, i have started to use this component and the second level of translations are not recognized for my debugging bar.
Example:

```
//messages.es.yml
#USUARIOS
usuarios:
    gestion: Gestion de usuarios
    listado: Listado de usuarios
    nuevo: Nuevo usuario
```

Using translate in controller or twig:

```
//SomeController.php
$breadcrumbs->addRouteItem($this->get("translator")->trans("usuarios.nuevo"), "backend_usuario_register");

// someFile.html.twig
{{ "usuarios.nuevo" | trans }}
```

In both cases return: usuarios.nuevo

Where is the problem? :/

**EDIT 1**

Fixed, the problem was that the keyword 'usuarios' was defined above as: usuarios: Usuarios.

Now I have another problem, how can I give a value to the primary id so that it leaves without error?

I have it now, but it returns error:

```
//messages.es.yml
#USUARIOS
usuarios: Usuarios
    gestion: Gestion de usuarios
    listado: Listado de usuarios
    nuevo: Nuevo usuario
```

Thank!

Comment: have you cleared the cache ? your yml is valid ?

Comment: I have cleared the cache and my yml is working with simple ids, for example " gestion: Gestion" return correctly "Gestion"